# Rude behavior in canteen

Tags: etiquette, requests, assertiveness, non-verbal-communication, responsibility

In our work place there are around 1100 employees. Majority of them collectively gather in factory canteen during break and take their lunch.This canteen  consists of  a  big hall with hundreds of chairs and tables are available with all required crockery.  When all personnel are seated they are served with lunch. All the available personnel are educated and having years of experience.  Unfortunately, I have seen following rude behavior which are sources of embarrassment for me.

1. People talk too loudly generating a lot of noise during lunch.
2. They do not take attention of cleanliness.
3. They drags chairs causing unnecessary noise.
4. Few of them even shout at the waiters.

Being a junior manager and in charge of canteen I have tried to educate people to stop these rude behaviors. But despite displaying clear instructions on notice board I cannot succeed.  I request please advice me what steps I should take to stop these rude behaviors.

Comment: I don’t think unethical is the correct term in this case. Possibly “rude”, or bad manners.

Comment: None of these sound like problems. How are these behaviors hurting your company, and what do you hope to accomplish here?

Comment: In my opinion decent behavior must be shown in all activities

Comment: Have others complained about this behavior such as have the waiters complained about being mistreated or someone complained about the noise in the canteen? It's important to not just use your standards as the baseline. If no one is complaining, it might not even be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

> People talk too loudly generating a lot of noise during lunch.

It's a room with *hundreds* of people in it having lunch, not a library! The basic physics of sound and human hearing mean if you've got hundreds of small groups of people having conversations in one room you're going to generate quite a lot of noise.

> They do not take attention of cleanliness.

This is a genuine issue - although one that is going to be difficult to stamp out entirely. If you have some clearly defined rules/policies that aren't being followed (returning trays, putting waste in bins etc) that aren't being followed you can stress these. Unfortunately I'd be surprised if you were able to enact/enforce any direct consequences on people who violate them. You could however try mass-emailing the staff indicating that they are responsible for this and that the increased load on cleaning staff to pick up the slack may lead to price increases in the canteen if not addressed.

> They drags chairs causing unnecessary noise.

While I agree that the sound is annoying - ultimately it's not a big deal. From what you describe it sounds as though this canteen has a hard floor - which is totally practical and makes sense as they are easy and quick to clean and are generally much harder wearing than carpet. Unfortunately they are also the sources of annoying noises like this and even worse they don't absorb noise either so the results are LOUD, while everyone picking up and placing their chairs every single time would alleviate the noise with the best will in the world you aren't going to achieve this - and attempting to police it persistently will just make you look petty.

> Few of them even shout at the waiters.

This is by far the biggest issue you mention and is completely unacceptable! Again I would communicate via e-mail etc to all staff that shouting at or otherwise abusing wait staff is unacceptable and that your staff have been instructed to refuse service to anyone behaving in this way (you'll obviously need to tell the staff that as well!)

Answer (score 0):

**A person is smart, people are dumb.**

If more than 50 people are sitting somewhere without work, they will engage in causal chit-chat. There will be noise, laughter and some people will be talking loud enough that everyone can hear them. All this is part of being a human. It is good to be engaging in conversation with others, instead of getting glued to the phones.

You also need to acknowledge that lunch is the free time of the workforce of your factory. People want to unwind, relax and have fun at that time so that they can get back to serious work for the remainder of the day.

Besides the above, your other concerns are valid. Let's address them one by one:

1. **Cleanliness**
   Since the meal is served to people, with them sitting and all tableware available at the table, there is no need for them to get up and grab something. This way, it is expected that the tables will be cleaned afterwards. This is true for all restaurants. For example, at McDonald's, it is expected that you will pick up your food and dispose off the trash. However, at a fancy place, you don't have to do that. The setup at your factory appears to be the later. If it is expected that people clean up after their meals, you need to:

   a. have signs placed on each table to clean up.
   b. have several trash cans nearby so that people can throw the garbage in those 
   and don't have to walk around carrying their things to throw.
2. **Dragging Chairs**
   You can add some signs suggesting taking of the things at the canteen. You can advise the person in private in a polite manner verbally not to do that.
3. **Shouting at waiters**
   This is one of the bitter truths of life. No amount of education, advice, summons can improve this behavior unless people themselves want to improve that. One will only be nice to serving people if they realize that they also humans, same as them but only at a different level of wealth distribution.

Comment: Welcome to IPS! Unfortunately, your answer doesn't really address the question right now. Could you [edit] to tell use how OP can make people see waiters as "humans"? And how can OP try to address the cleanliness issue (what you are suggesting isn't clear right now)? Also, could you add details has how OP should go about advising the person "in a polite manner [..] not to do that"? Finally, please take some time to read ["How do I write a good answer"](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/21067).

Answer (score 0):

Putting signs or giving written advice often is ignored or people have no idea when the advice really applies. They think it's not made for them.

It would be better to have peer guests tell their colleagues to quiet down, to pick up their trash or to have a waiter nicely explain it's not nice to shout at them. Doing this right when the situation arises and to a particular person has more effect than giving general rules to all of them.
The direct approach shows to them they are addressed right now and the advice is not just some theoretical thing.

Of course you need some time to make this work and you need to find people who feel disturbed by this behavior and who are subtle enough to address the problem in a positive way.